# Как пофиксить ошибку: «XMLHttpRequest cannot load *** due to access control checks.»?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Я использую сервис [Postcalc.ru](https://postcalc.ru/) для расчёта цены на сайте. Когда я отправляю запрос на сервер, я получаю ошибку

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.postcalc.ru/?f=101000&t=190000&w=1000 due to access control checks.
```

Вот так выглядит мой запрос:

```
var getDeliveryPriceRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
getDeliveryPriceRequest.open("GET", "http://test.postcalc.ru/?f=101000&t=190000&w=1000", true);
getDeliveryPriceRequest.send();
getDeliveryPriceRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log(getDeliveryPriceRequest.response);
};
```

Как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: Для себя определился, на том, что запрос делает php и результат возвращает мне.

Comment: _Как это можно пофиксить?_ На клиенте - никак, пока сервер не будет разрешать CORS запросы. Сейчас этого нет, потому и ошибка.

Comment: @hindmost То есть мне нужно искать для этого другой сервис?

Comment: Необязательно. Можно использовать серверный прокси-скрипт для запросов к сервису, но для этого нужен свой сервер.

Comment: с какого адреса происходит запрос?